# How to use requests to login to this website

Tags: python, forms, python-requests

I'm trying to automate some tasks with python, and webscraping. but first, I need to login to a website I have an account on.

I've seen several examples on stack overflow, but for some reason, this website won't let me login using requests. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

The webpage:
https://www.americanbulls.com/Signin.aspx?lang=en

the form variables:
ctl00$MainContent$uEmail
ctl00$MainContent$uPassword

Is it the variable names have '$' in them?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
sys.path.append('C:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor')
import requests
import sys
import time

EMAIL = '<my_email>'
PASSWORD = '<my_password>'

URL = 'https://www.americanbulls.com/Signin.aspx?lang=en'

# Start a session so we can have persistant cookies

session = requests.session()


#This is the form data that the page sends when logging in
login_data = {
    'ctl00$MainContent$uEmail': EMAIL,
    'ctl00$MainContent$uPassword': PASSWORD
}

# Authenticate
r = session.post(URL, data=login_data, timeout=15, verify=True)

# Try accessing a page that requires you to be logged in
r = session.get('https://www.americanbulls.com/members/SignalPage.aspx?lang=en&Ticker=SQ')
print(r.url)
```

Comment: I would look at [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) that would be better suited for this task

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted a form using test@test.test as the email and test as the password, and when I looked at the headers of the request I'd sent in the network tab of chrome dev tools it said I submitted the following form data.

```
ctl00$ScriptManager1:ctl00$MainContent$UpdatePanel|ctl00$MainContent$btnSubmit
__LASTFOCUS:
__EVENTTARGET:
__EVENTARGUMENT:
__VIEWSTATE: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
__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR:ECDA716A
__EVENTVALIDATION:/wEdAAVswH4c0JxRe30eXDiX0bhcXr7XOgipC8DNcjKl0sbO7fwNII+YQgXfxmh/KZz6Myr4IcjYoaGuA6R78NuEHgsNQX9+ScDGDIM47zqhQCjs5Ynd+DEUmo0/Xv9Oy6tQgLO7ip/G
ctl00$mMain:{&quot;selectedItemIndexPath&quot;:&quot;0i0&quot;,&quot;checkedState&quot;:&quot;&quot;}
ctl00$MainMenu:{&quot;selectedItemIndexPath&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;checkedState&quot;:&quot;&quot;}
ctl00$FreeRegisterMenu:{&quot;selectedItemIndexPath&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;checkedState&quot;:&quot;&quot;}
ctl00$MembershipBenefits:{&quot;selectedItemIndexPath&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;checkedState&quot;:&quot;&quot;}
ctl00$SearchBox$State:{&quot;rawValue&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;validationState&quot;:&quot;&quot;}
ctl00$SearchBox:Enter Symbol
ctl00$MainContent$uEmail:test@test.test
ctl00$MainContent$uPassword:test
ctl00$MainContent$ASPxCheckBox1:I
ctl00$SupportMenu:{&quot;selectedItemIndexPath&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;checkedState&quot;:&quot;&quot;}
ctl00$LanguagesMenu:{&quot;selectedItemIndexPath&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;checkedState&quot;:&quot;&quot;}
DXScript:1_304,1_185,1_298,1_211,1_221,1_188,1_182,1_290,1_296,1_279,1_198,1_209,1_217,1_201
DXCss:1_40,1_50,1_53,1_51,1_4,1_16,1_13,0_4617,0_4621,1_14,1_17,Styles/Site.css,img/favicon.ico,https://adservice.google.com/adsid/integrator.js?domain=www.americanbulls.com,https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/static/3p_cookie.html
__ASYNCPOST:true
ctl00$MainContent$btnSubmit:Sign In
```

Your code looks great. It just looks like the script is failing because you're not submitting everything that the browser would normally submit. You could try continuing down the path you are on, submit all of the extra form data, and hope you don't have to bother with adding a CSRF token (a CSRF token is a randomly generated string that you're required to send back), or you can do as Sidharth Shah sugggested and use [Selenium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)).

There is a Firefox extension for Selenium that will allow you to start recording your mouse and keyboard actions, and then when you are done, you can export the results in Python. That Python code will depend on the Selenium library and a Selenium Chrome/Firefox/IE driver. When you run your Python code, a new browser window will open up, controlled by the selenium driver and your Python code. It's pretty cool, your basically writing Python code that controls a browser window. You will have to modify the Python code that the Firefox extension gives you a little bit to read all of the data from the page and start doing stuff with it after you're logged in, but the code for opening the browser window, navigating to athe login page, filling in your login credentials and submitting the form, and navigating to other pages after you're logged in will all be written for you.

Comment: Thanks so much, I will look into this as-well.